# How to make a constant script on html page

Tags: php, html, node.js, chat, real-time

I know the title sounds a little weird but the following will explain it,

I have a website with php chat script with javascript timer to refresh messages each 5 seconds, which makes it so annoying.

I'm planning to switch to nodejs and make a real-time chat app.

To connect the user to the server i'm using the following :

```
<script>
    var c = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8001");
</script>
```

This script is necessary on every page for the user to stay connected, but the problem is that it's gonna create a new websocket each time which is bad for the performance and load time, i've noticed on facebook that the navigation bar and chat bar does not reload when navigating, so how to achieve that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to setup a window object and assign to it globally?

Comment: @HassanAzimi No i don't, would you have any documentation / tutorial about that ? Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In facebook used [singl page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), that not reload page when your click on any internal links.
See to angular or other spa frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
Based on your answer, i'm gonna have to re-code most of the website, right ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you first read about [html5 history api](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/). Probably, for you it will be easier to modify the application, rather than rewrite from scratch.